# Can I separate a LCD screen from the board?

Tags: pcb, soldering, lcd, motherboard, character-lcd

I am using this 2x16 LCD
[https://www.amazon.com/GeeekPi-Interface-Adapter-Backlight-Raspberry/dp/B086VVT4NH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086VVT4NH)

I am trying to make the LCD ultra slim to fit in my project. Can I dismantle 2x16 LCD and separate the screen from the board then connect them again through wires? Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean to separate the glass from module PCB or the I2C adapter PCB from the module PCB?

Comment: no i mean the glass from the module PCB

Comment: The black blobs on the bottom of the board are (probably HD44780 compatible) controller chips. Without those all you have is the bare LCD which is very complex to drive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no, it is generally not worth trying to modify the module to extend the connection between glass and controller PCB.

There is no simple way to extend the connections between module PCB and glass. There are conductive rubber strips to connect the glass to PCB as the glass can't be soldered to.

So even to connect wires between glass and original pcb, you would need some custom PCB, maybe even flexible PCB.

Comment: so do you have any recommendations for a slim LCD?

Comment: @MohamedEssam product recommendation is off-topic.

Comment: okay thank you for your effort

Comment: @MohamedEssam those character displays are from the 80s I think, and have barely changed since. If you use a more modern graphics screen there will be many more options. For example search for 128x64 displays from any regular supplier and you'll see loads come up. Libraries to create text are readily available.

Comment: @Jon than you so much jon